# Is there a criterion to check if n choose k is divisible by 4?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a criterion to check if $4 | {{n} \choose {k}}$?

For example if $n = 4$ there are two values of $k$ when $4 | {{n} \choose {k}}$. When $n = 14$ or $n = 16$ there are also some $k$ where $4 | {{n} \choose {k}}$ is passed. However there is no such $k$ for $n = 15$ or $n = 127$. So is there a change to check it without calculating $ n \choose k$?

Comment: Yes. [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) gives you the exact power of any prime that divides a given binomial coefficient.

Comment: The result is: Write both $k$ and $n-k$ in base $2$ (=binary). Then add them with the grade school method with carries and all. Then $4\mid \binom n k$ if and only if there were at least two carries. Equivalently: count the number of $1$s in the base two representations of A) in $k$ and $n-k$, and B) in $n$. If the former outnumber the latter by at least two, then you have divisibility by four.

Comment: And, it follows that all the binomial coefficients $\binom nk$ ($n$ fixed, $k$ varies) are odd if and only if $n=2^\ell-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the comments have provided definitive resolutions. Here is a way to get to that fact. (Esp. the one about adding the numbers in binary)

Consider the fact that
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
For $4$ to divide this, examine $\nu_2(n!), \nu_2(k!), \nu_2((n-k)!)$. By Legendre's, the values of such are

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^i}\right\rfloor \\ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2^i}\right\rfloor \\ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n-k}{2^i}\right\rfloor$$

We need

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^i}\right\rfloor - \left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2^i}\right\rfloor + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n-k}{2^i}\right\rfloor\right) > 1$$

Observe that if $a+b=c$, then $\lfloor c \rfloor \geq \lfloor a \rfloor + \lfloor b \rfloor$ (proven by simple casework). Thus, it suffices to show that for some $i$,

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^i}\right\rfloor > \left\lfloor\frac{k}{2^i}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n-k}{2^i}\right\rfloor$$

When this happens, it is equivalent to say that

$$\left\lbrace\frac{k}{2^i}\right\rbrace + \left\lbrace\frac{n-k}{2^i}\right\rbrace \geq 1$$

Multiplying by $2^i$, we need

$$k \bmod 2^i + (n-k) \bmod 2^i \geq 2^i$$

Hopefully it is evident from the binary representations here.

Edit: To be clear, check if $k \text{ AND } (n-k) \neq 0$, or if $n = 2^i - 1$.

Comment: Something is wrong. For $10 \choose 5$ we have $252$ which is divisible by $4$, but id not dibisible by modulo form ($5 \mod 4 = 1$ and $(10-5) \mod 4 = 1$)

Comment: $i$ can be any number. So 5 mod 8 + 5 mod 8 > 8.

Comment: Hint: Check the binary representations, add them and check for carryig.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.